# CSS - off canvas issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation-6

I have a page, where I have divs setup to give a parallax effect on scrolling. This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beqswr69/49/).

I have a problem when I add a foundations off canvas menu, then I can't scroll down anymore. How can I fix that and be able to have the same scrolling effect with the off canvas menu?

This is the html with Foundations added off canvas:

```
<body>
  <div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
      <div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner" data-off-canvas-wrapper>
        <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>

          <!-- Close button -->
          <button class="close-button" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>

          <!-- Menu -->
          <ul class="vertical menu">
            <li><a href="#">Foundation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dot</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ZURB</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Com</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Slash</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
          <div id="app">
             <div id="bg">
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-one">
            <div class="panel-inner">
              <div class="content">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
                <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.</p>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>

         <div class="panel panel-two">
           <div class="panel-inner">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.</p>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

I tested if I remove `position: fixed;` for the `content` class, then I can scroll down, but I need to keep the content somehow fixed so that it doesn't move upon scroll, how can I achieve that with functioning off-canvas?

I managed to get it half-working somehow by overwriting the foundation classes, but it is not smooth at all, now I can scroll the whole page content, but the off-canvas is not fixed when it is opened, I have tried by setting `off-canvas-left` with `position:fixed` but that didn't work:

```
.off-canvas-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  position: static;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.off-canvas-wrapper-inner {
  height: auto;
}

.off-canvas {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: So do you want the foundation off-canvas menu to stay fixed at the top of the screen? What should happen to the menu when you scroll? Is the current fiddle you have linked how you want it to look but have a menu fixed at the top?

Comment: I want off canvas as it is, but I can't scroll down to the panel-two, when I have it. Fiddle was just to show the scrolling effect that I would like to keep when having off canvas. When I do have off canvas, I can't do any scrolling.

Comment: I have placed an answer with an attempt to solve this

Comment: where did youo post it? looking forward to see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code you provided and added an off canvas menu. I hope this is what you needed.

https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/beqswr69/58/

HTML

```
<body>

  <!-- Close button -->
  <button class="close-button" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>

  <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <ul class="vertical menu">
      <li><a href="#">Foundation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dot</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ZURB</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Com</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Slash</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="bg">
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-one">
    <div class="panel-inner">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit
          ligula pharetra.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-two">
    <div class="panel-inner">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit
        ligula pharetra.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-three">
    <div class="panel-inner">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit
        ligula pharetra.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

CSS

```
#offCanvas {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.close-button {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#bg {
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/800?random');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: zoom 10s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  }
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.panel {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: 5;
}

.panel-fixed {
  z-index: 1;
}

.panel-inner {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-fixed .panel-inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Base */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel-two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.panel-three {
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not working, I can scroll, but there are many other issues with this, content is not fixed in the panel one, and it goes to much down on the scroll.

Comment: I have added the link to the JSFiddle to make sure you have the most recent edit.

Comment: I have tried your most recent updated, but that is not working as well

Comment: Ah I am sorry about that. I thought you wanted to have the menu and contents of the first block fixed and then have the other blocks rise over them causing that parallax effect. That current JSFiddle was my best interpretation of what you needed.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your attempt and sorry for not making myself clear.

Comment: To give me a bit more information as I want to continue to help, what is wrong with the current JSFiddle, how should it look compared to how it looks at the moment?

Comment: In my fiddle, I haven't posted the whole html, since there is alot of it, and I used template engine for it so it would take me alot of time, to translate it to normal html, but in short notes, I have a button, on which I open and close menu off canvas, off canvas should of course not be visible, as I noticed you haven't used the Foundation proposed syntax for doing the off canvas as well, maybe that was also the reason way it didn't work, I have tried your suggestion in my project, not on fiddle and it also didn't work, the menu should be fixed, but the page itself should be scrollable

Comment: I have also updated my question with what I have managed to come up with, it is still not working completely, but hoping to get it somehow working as I want it

Comment: Okay, that is another attempt. I have tried my best to understand what it is you need. That JSFiddle shows a working sample of the code I have placed in the answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to save the JSFiddle, that link now is the current one and not an older version I was working on.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you!